# Batch file to remove double quotes from csv

Tags: batch, batch-file, csv

**My file is tab separated file(TSV) with 5 columns**
I have local drive path on my first column but each image name from path contains double quotes.

Path
C:\Users\magoo\"flower.jpg"
C:\Users\magoo\"flower2.jpg"

Code I tried but I am not able to remove double quotes.

```
@ECHO Off  
SETLOCAL  
(  
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1* delims=" %%a IN (input.csv) DO ECHO %%~a,%%b  
)>output.csv  
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: If it is a one-time job only, open the CSV with a text editor and search/replace. Much easier.

Comment: This is not a one time job.I want to automate this process

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a linux based system, i would recommend using sed :

```
sed -i 's/"//g' filename
```

If not, this article here seems to be pointing in the right direction, but am no batch expert myself : https://www.robvanderwoude.com/bht.php#Strip

PowerShell alternative :

```
(Get-Content C:\Tess.txt) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace '"' } > C:\Tess.txt
```

Comment: `sed`  is potentially available on Windows via [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) and other, similar projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with this code for testing :

```bat
@echo off
Title Replace Double Quotes into a Variable
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Var1=C:\Users\magoo\"flower.jpg"
echo Variable Var1 with quotes !Var1!
pause
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Call :Dequote !Var1! NewVar1
echo New Variable NewVar1 without quotes !NewVar1!
pause
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set Var2=C:\Users\magoo\"flower2.jpg"
echo Variable Var2 with quotes !Var2!
pause
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
Call :Dequote !Var2! NewVar2
echo New Variable NewVar2 without quotes !NewVar2!
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
pause
Exit
::::::::::::Function DeQuote:::::::::::::
:Dequote <Var> <NewVar to Set>
set MyString=%1
set StrToFind="
set NewStr=
set %2=!MyString:%StrToFind%=%NewStr%!
Exit /b
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

**Edit :** 
In your case you can try something like that :

```bat
@echo off
Title Replace Double Quotes into a Variable
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
FOR /f "delims=, tokens=1-5" %%a IN ('Type input.csv') DO (
    Set "MyVar1=%%a"
    Rem We dequote the variable MyVar1 and we set it to a new on NewVar1
    Call :Dequote !MyVar1! NewVar1
    echo !NewVar1!,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e
    )
)>output.csv
Pause & Exit
::::::::::::Function DeQuote:::::::::::::
:Dequote <OldVar> <NewVar to Set>
set MyString=%1
set StrToFind="
set NewStr=
set %2=!MyString:%StrToFind%=%NewStr%!
Exit /b
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```